# How to open gvim to current window in command line?

Tags: ubuntu, vim, gvim

Background: I'm using Ubuntu and have an existing Gvim GUI opened. Now I want to edit a file from command line `gvim test.txt`, the command will open another new Gvim GUI. Is there any method to open that file to current GUI but not new one? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `--remote` and `--remote-silent` options:

```
gvim --remote-silent text.txt
```

Vim's internal help system is excellent; try

```
:help clientserver
```

Comment: Perfect! First time to know `--remote`. Thank you.